# Adding a new constructor to a datatype after declaration

Tags: haskell, constructor, algebraic-data-types

I have a requirement to add some new constructors to a datatype after it's module has been loaded. The pseudo code may seem like this:

```
import MyModule

data MyType = NewConstructor
```

In the above example `MyType` has been previously defined in `MyModule`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. A datatype is closed. And it is a good thing otherwise, how can you predict how previsouly defined function will behave?

Several workarounds exist, here are some off the top of my head:

1. Use a function as a constructor. e.g. `myExtendedType = MyType 42`;
2. Use your own type and a mapping function. e.g. `data MyExtendedType = MyExtendedType; toMyType MyExtendedType = MyType 42`;
3. Wrap the existing datatype:

   ```
   import MyModule as Old

   data MyExtendedType = FromOld (MyType Int) | MyExtendedType

   foo (FromOld m) = Old.foo m
   foo MyExtendedType = undefined
   ```

Comment: How about type synonyms? Can I use them?

Comment: type synonyms provide.... an exact synonym, so you can't extend an existing constructor thanks to them.